# pthread_cond_signal() causes process to halt

Tags: c, posix, ipc

```
pthread_mutex_unlock(&shmseg->shm_mutex);
fprintf(stdout,"unlocked mutex\n");
pthread_cond_broadcast(&shmseg->donewriting);
fprintf(stdout,"signalled condition\n");
```

The process that's calling this code displays the first print statement but then just hangs and doesn't run the second print statement. In the meantime, another process is waiting on this condition (which is a member of shmseg, a struct cast from a segment of shared memory returned from mmap that both processes have access to). I'll gladly share any other segment of the code which anyone feels might be relevant. As far as I can tell the mutex and condition variables have been set to be process shared,

```
pthread_mutexattr_t m_attr;
pthread_condattr_t c_attr;

pthread_mutexattr_init(&m_attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&m_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

pthread_condattr_init(&c_attr);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&c_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

pthread_cond_init(&seg->donewriting, &c_attr);
pthread_mutex_init(&seg->shm_mutex, &m_attr);
```

Those statements were  run by the other process previously.

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to diagnose the problem with the information given. And no, I can't tell you specifically what information is missing because it's impossible to know the full context of your code. It'll be best if you could post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the problem.

Comment: Double check the synchronization handling. A hang inside the pthread functions is often a sign of the corruption of the synchronization structures. (E.g. on some platforms, double pthread_mutex_unlock() would cause next pthread_mutex_lock() to hang.)